# view events not being called in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

i've got a little problem with my custom `UITabBarController` class. My `UICustomTabBarController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`. In my `didSelectItem` event I implemented the following code:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    [self showActivityIndicator];
}
```

I my `showActivityIndicator` method I add a activity indicator to my current view. It works just fine.
Now i would like to remove the activity indicator when the current view will disappear.

**i found the following events:**

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
NSLog(@"hello");
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     NSLog(@"hello");
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     NSLog(@"hello");
}
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion  {
    NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

Unfortunately none of them are working. They are not being called. Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: how this view is displayed? is it pushed to a navigation controller? or its view is added as subview?

Comment: Which view do  mean? the activity indicator? it is a subview of the current view. [self.view addsubview:XX]

Answer (score 0):

Is the delegate property for UITabBar is set in the .h file ?  ?

i.e. `<UITabBarDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

Comment: my .h file goes like this @interface UICustomTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>  . I just changed it, but no success.